# Are there any examples of predators that ambush scavengers?

Tags: predation

I'm specifically asking about animals that use a hunting strategy revolving around hanging around cadavers to attack animals attracted to the cadaver, or even leaving part of their catches out to lure scavengers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saltwater crocodiles in Australia are reputed to do this; storing meat under water and later eating the fish and crustaceans that are attracted.

Having trouble finding a good source for this.

Article from national news service below.

https://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2004/01/15/2045125.htm

Feel free to add references if you can find them.